# Value sum with previous

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I want to create a new column, `Z`, the values are calculated with previous.
I will explain below.

Here is the pseudo data:

```
#dt
     C         P
  8.5%  100.9063
13.13%  105.9961
15.75%  112.4102
  7.5%  101.2188
```

What I want is:

```
     C         P            Z
  8.5%  100.9063   0.96792566
13.13%  105.9961   0.93507648   
15.75%  112.4102   0.90311943
  7.5%  101.2188   0.87417633
```

The first value, 0.96792566, is calculated by `P/(100*(1+C/2))` or `100.9063/(100*(1+8.5%/2))`.
The second to the last are calculated by `(P-(C/2)*100*SUM(Z))/((1+C/2)*100)`, where `Z` in this formula is to add to previous one.
I wrote these formulas from excel viewpoint.
For example,

```
`0.93507648 = (105.9961-(13.13%/2)*100*SUM(0.96792566))/((1+13.13%/2)*100)`
`0.90311943 = (112.4102-(15.75%/2)*100*SUM(0.96792566, 0.93507648))/((1+ 15.75%/2)*100)`
```

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. The formulas are from excel viewpoint. That is my difficulty that I can calculate what I want in excel but how can I do in R.

Comment: I added the screenshot of how I did in excel. Is that clarify the question?

Comment: The first does not need `sum`. In R, I think it should be `P/(100*(1+C/2))`. However, I have no idea for another one.

Comment: I searched for the rolling sum and `cumsum` but still have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to recursively update in a `for` loop

```
library(readr)
v1 <- numeric(nrow(dt))
v1[1] <- dt$P[1]/(100*(1+parse_number(dt$C[1])/100/2))    
C <- parse_number(dt$C)/100 
for(i in 2:nrow(dt))  v1[i] <- (dt$P[i]-(C[i]/2)*100* sum(v1[1:(i-1)]))/((1+C[i]/2)*100)
dt$Z <- v1
dt$Z
#[1] 0.9679257 0.9350318 0.9031231 0.8741783
```

#### data

```
dt <- structure(list(C = c("8.5%", "13.13%", "15.75%", "7.5%"), P = c(100.9063, 
105.9961, 112.4102, 101.2188)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: My problem is not for percentage. It shows numeric values in R actually. The problem is second formula...

Comment: what do you mean "different"?

Comment: @PeterChen  Can you now check the output

Comment: It works. Awesome. However, if the data is large, is it possible to avoid looping process?

Comment: @PeterChen  Usual way is `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE` or `accumulate`, from `purrr` but here the input depends on multiple column values, making it tricky to do that